# How to parse an XML file with multiple non-specific elements

Tags: python, xml, beautifulsoup, fogbugz, fogbugz-api

I'm trying to parse a list of cases that is returned from the Fogbugz API.

Current code:

```
from fogbugz import FogBugz
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import fbSettings

fb = FogBugz(fbSettings.URL, fbSettings.TOKEN)

resp = fb.search(q='project:"Python Testing"',cols='ixBug')

print resp.cases.case.ixbug.string
```

The problem is that the XML has multiple cases returned simply as case. For instance my test search back the following:

```
<response>
<cases count="3">
 <case ixbug="133529" operations="edit,assign,resolve,email,remind">
  <ixbug>
   133529
  </ixbug>
 </case>
 <case ixbug="133528" operations="edit,assign,resolve,email,remind">
  <ixbug>
   133528
  </ixbug>
 </case>
 <case ixbug="133527" operations="edit,assign,resolve,email,remind">
  <ixbug>
   133527
  </ixbug>
 </case>
</cases>
</response>
```

But

```
print resp.cases.case.ixbug.string
```

only returns the first case number in the XML, ignoring the other two. How can I modify my print statement to return all three case numbers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the [docs](https://developers.fogbugz.com/?W199#toc_14):

```
from fogbugz import FogBugz
import fbSettings

fb = FogBugz(fbSettings.URL, fbSettings.TOKEN)

resp = fb.search(q='project:"Python Testing"',cols='ixBug')

# printing
for case in resp.cases.findAll('case'):
    print case.ixbug.string

# store in a list
l = [case.ixbug.string for case in resp.cases.findAll('case')]
```